# errorTable 'college.college' doesn't exist : query error

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
    ini_set('display_errors',1); 
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    include 'conn.php';
    // Attempt select query execution
    $db_select = mysqli_select_db($conn,'college'); 

    if (!$db_select) { 
        die("Database selection failed:: " . mysql_error($conn)); 
    }else{

    }  //You don't need a ; like you do in SQL
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM college") or die("error".mysqli_error($conn));

    echo "<table>"; // start a table tag in the HTML
    $result = array();
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){   //Creates a loop to loop through results
        echo "<tr><td>" . $row['city'] . "</td><td>" . $row['clients'] . "</td></tr>";  //$row['index'] the index here is a field name
    }
    echo "</table>"; //Close the table in HTML

    mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

I am getting error in query statemenet that table college does exist. I have created table college in phpmyadmin and populated it with fake values, but still I am getting query error. The error is in line 14.

Comment: what code in conn.php file? Place all the conn.php file code here.

Comment: what happen when you run `use college;SELECT * FROM college;` command in mysql console?